# Do all Second Order ODEs (homogenous) have three solutions?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

All differential equations of the form [image]

can be solved by the relevant quadratic equation that is their characteristics equation. However, although the quadratic provides two solutions, is it not true that $y=0$ is also a solution, though trivial? And, why is it that this trivial case is always ignored?

Comment: There are infinitely many solutions. The general solution is a linear combination $Af+Bg$ of two solutions $f,g$ you know how to compute. The solution $y=0$ is given by taking $A=B=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trivial solution $y=0$ isn't generally of any interest.

What is a differential equation? It's one that relates the rates of changes of some function or sets of functions. The problem isn't really of any interest if the system doesn't change at all. For example, if we're modelling population, it wouldn't be too interesting if our population was zero... always.

In the second order problem you present, notice that the trivial solution works regardless of parameters $a,b,c$. Sure it solves the equation, but it bypasses all the crucial information.

So we say a second order homogenous ODE has *two* solutions. If the characteristic equation gives different roots, say $r_1,r_2$, then we have

$$y=c_1 e^{r_1 x}+c_2 e^{r_1 x}$$

We know this since any linear combination of solutions is a solution itself. If that's the case, then we can also add in the trivial solution.

$$y=c_1 e^{r_1 x}+c_2 e^{r_1 x} +c_3 \cdot 0$$
$$y=c_1 e^{r_1 x}+c_2 e^{r_1 x}$$

But that doesn't really change things much at all, does it?

Comment: As Andre points out, though, $y=0$ indeed is a solution. I hope I didn't make it seem otherwise. It's the case where the initial conditions cause your constants to vanish. It's just that in physical systems, we often aren't quite that interested in this case.